# Allow all clients to send Commands EXCEPT host client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

Is there a way to do this? I want to prevent the local client running on the server (host) from sending some commands while allowing all the remote clients to do so. Is this possible? Currently the code below runs on ALL clients. Is there a way to modify the script to make it function in this way? Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Player_Data : NetworkBehaviour
{

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        CmdSendServerData();
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSendServerData()
    {
        DisplayDataOnScreen("CmdSendServerData Called");
    }

    [Server]
    void DisplayDataOnScreen(string data)
    {
        GameObject infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += data + "\n";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isServer` property. You can check it before cammand call.

```
public class Player_Data : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {    
        if (isLocalPlayer && !isServer)
        {
            CmdSendServerData();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSendServerData()
    {            
        DisplayDataOnScreen("CmdSendServerData Called");          
    }

    [Server]
    void DisplayDataOnScreen(string data)
    {
        GameObject infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += data + "\n";
    } 
}
```